Can the time period between simultaneous events be made arbitrarily long?
(not a prank question. We know simultaneous events may be non-simultaneous to moving observers)
The question comes from the classic "train struck by lightning twice" scenario: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity
Quick recap: An observer (Bob) calls two events simultaneous if they:

took place at the same distance from him

and

the light from the two events reach him at the same time


Suppose we put Bob on a train with 2 ticking bombs, one at the back and one at the front, with Bob exactly in the middle.
The train runs fast. The back-bomb explodes, but (by our clocks) the light takes a long time to overtake Bob. Right before it reaches Bob, the front-bomb explodes. Bob races towards this light, so it hits him right away, simultaneously with the light from the back-bomb.
Bob measures the distances to the explosions to be equal, so he says the two bombs went off at the same time.
By increasing the train's speed, or length, or both, can we stage two events which are arbitrarily far apart by our clocks, and still be called simultaneous by Bob?
Can Bob rightfully claim I boiled and ate an egg in zero time?

You might want to put the bombs and Bob in different reference frames. If both he and the bombs are on the train, with him in the middle, then Bob sees the detonations as simultaneous (since he is at rest relative to them and, the bombs being equidistant, sees their light at the same time).

The answers to the two questions in your final paragraphs are yes and no, as you'll see instantly if you draw (or just imagine) Bob's x-axis in a diagram where your own x-axis is horizontal.  Instead of repeatedly asking other people to do all your work for you, maybe you should read a book on relativity.

What exactly about the standard formula $v\Delta x/c^2$ are you unclear about?

idk why you are making this so complicated. If an event is simultaneous in "the rest" frame, then $\Delta s^2 = -\Delta x^2$ is invariant. In any moving frame $\Delta s'^2 = \Delta s^2$, so $\Delta t'^2 = \Delta x'^2- \Delta x^2$ Figure it out from there.

Bob can't claim you boiled and ate an egg in zero time. On the contrary, the time between boiling and eating the egg will always be longer in another inertial frame moving relative to you- that's simple time dilation.

"An observer (Bob) calls two events simultaneous if they: took place at the same distance from him and [...]" Why would the distance be requires to be the same? Can two events taking place at different distances not happen simultaneously?

This is easy to calculate directly from the Lorentz transform. In one frame let one of the events be at the origin $(ct_0,x_0)=(0,0)$ and let the other event be simultaneous at $(ct_1,x_1)=(0,L)$.
Then the Lorentz transform gives $(ct'_0,x'_0)=(0,0)$ and $$(ct'_1,x'_1)=\left(\frac{vL}{c\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}},\frac{L}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\right)$$

By increasing the train's speed, or length, or both, can we stage two events which are arbitrarily far apart by our clocks, and still be called simultaneous by Bob?

Yes. As $v$ approaches $c$ we find that $t'_1$ increases without bound.

Can Bob rightfully claim I boiled and ate an egg in zero time?

No. That is a completely different question that is not at all related to the first question. There is no frame where you boiling an egg is simultaneous with you eating that same egg.

Nice answer (+1) Suppose I send a light pulse as I start to boil the egg, and I send a second light pulse as I start to eat the egg. By coincidence, the first light pulse makes 1 full revolution around a passing black hole. The second light pulse is not very much affected (since the fast moving massive object has passed by). As a result of the detour, both pulses arrive at the same time to a distant observer in another galaxy. Is this scenario possible by special/general relativity?

@James something like that could happen. Maybe not with exactly 1 orbit, but some large amount of gravitational deflection. You could also just use a strategically placed mirror in flat spacetime to keep things easier.

thank you. If the two light pulses arrive at the same time for an observer, does this mean that the 2 events are fundamentally simultaneous for this observer in special relativity, or is there a more metaphysical concept of simultaneity used in special relativity?

@James even in SR with only inertial observers using only inertial frames, receiving two signals simultaneously does not imply that they were sent simultaneously. And receiving them at different times does not imply that they were sent at different times.
